# Is it possible to access the files stored in the cloud from the U1 client in Unity? 

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

Is it possible to access the files stored in the cloud from the U1 client in Unity?

At this moment, I can only access the blank "Shared with me" folder on my PC or the folders, with no possibility to open them from the client.

Until now, I used to go to the U1 website log on and access contacts and files from there, but I think that since there is the client embedded in Unity, there should be a way to access it without having to go away from the client and then back.

Is there, though?

Comment: Yes, you activate the sync between your account and your pc.

Comment: I have read that you drag and drop files or folders to the "Shared with me" folder, but this is from PC to U1. What I am asking is from the cloud to the PC. The files have been uploaded from my Droid phone straight to U1.

Comment: I believe you have to have a folder in your Home folder named like the one you have in Ubuntu one Cloud, so you can activate the sync and the files you have in the cloud get downloaded to your pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Ubuntu One from the Launcher or the Dash, the Cloud Folders tab will list all your cloud folders, and you can tick them to say that you want them synced with the machine you're on.

Comment: I can access the files uploaded to the cloud from my PC using this method. But is it possible to open files on my PC that I have uploaded to my cloud from other devices using the client?

Comment: Certainly. You can sync any cloud folder to your PC; all files that are put in those folders will be synced to the PC, regardless of whether you upload them from your PC or from other devices.